# Why is there a staff_typ_id attribute?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, data-modeling

I'v created a ER model in data modeler and one of the entity is automatically setting a primary key even though I dont want a primary key to that particular entity.. here is a screenshot As you can see on logical model there is no staff_type_id[image: As you can see on logical model there is no staff_type_id]
[image: but the relational model has staff_type_id]

but the relational model has staff_type_id
why is this happening? its creating a problem while i implement the database. Please help :(

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no problem in that, if you notice you are linking the two tables with a relation of 1:N and you can't link entities that don't have primary key. it's the best to create a primary key for every linked entity. How you can link between entities without foreign key and primary key?!

generally, it's recommended to give every linked entity primary key.

I don't understand how this is a problem! can you explain more?

Comment: well i have an entity called staff that is the supertype for entity staff_type.. so basically the primary key for the staff gets passed down to staff_type as a foreign key. and because it is a subtype i dont want primary keys to that entity

Comment: if you mean that "supertype" is the father and "subtype" is the son that inherent from it, then your answer is wrong! because you must create two primary keys (one per father table and one per son), and to link the two like so


create table Father  {
ID varchar(10) primary key,
......
}


create table son  {
ID varchar(10) primary key,
.......,
constraint FK1 foreign key (ID) references Father(ID) on delete cascade on update cascade
}

Comment: the inherent will give the son all the attributes and it should implemented by the way that I mentioned in the previous comment, otherwise you can't do the inherent stuff.